# How to create archive table for improve search performance in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, search

Currently, my project have a lot of record in table company_job(about 1 milions record) include:

1. ~ 100,000 record will be using to search and need to improve search performance
2. ~ 900,000 record is job out of date to search and need to archive

I want to create new archive table such as company_job_archive to move job in #2 from company_job table.
This table also accept to find job by company_job_id when needed.

Do you have any solution for my case? Thank you so much!

Comment: It sounds like archive doesn't mean delete, so perhaps a new attribute, `archived_at` as a time stamp, would be sufficient, along with scopes to allow searches against live, archived, and all records.

Comment: Agree. A million records is not a lot if properly indexed. Add an `archived_at` timestamp and set that when the record is stale, either at the point at which it becomes stale, or with a nightly task or something, then `add_index :company_jobs, :archived_at` Then when you search with `where(archived_at: nil)`, it will only sift through unarchived records, of which are only about 100,000 records.